# What is the equivalent of options(scipen=999) in Python

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, scientific-notation

What is the equivalent of options(scipen=999) for setting scientific notation off in Python.

Comment: are we supposed to guess what `options(scipen=999)` is ???

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, it's `np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)`

If you want to do it without NumPy, `'%f' % your_number`

Please provide more info on when and why you need this so that people can help you accordingly and this didn't help.

Comment: Thanks. np.set_printoptions(suppress=True), This worked.

Comment: @Bhaskar Please mark it as the right answer then :)

Comment: Sorry! Newbie here. I marked it right. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

For a pandas equivalent, say if you wanted to limit output to 2 decimals:

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.2f' % x)
```

You only have to do this once per runtime